# Disable Nebular context Menus on conditions

Tags: angular, angular6, nebular

I am using Angular 6 with Nebular, I need to display nebular context menu on table row and the context menu should be enabled or disabled based on table column status.
[image: Html code[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTS9F.png)
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBOST.png)
[[image: expected]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzqex.png)

use case is something like attached screenshot but menu item should disable based on status if status is assigned them may be different menu item should disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set a menu item as `disabled` (here is a list of available Nebular menu properties https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/menu/api#nbmenuitem).
But I believe in your case you can simply use [nbPopover] directive with a custom list of actions inside. Here is a quick example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vsh77o-rybmjw

Hope it helps!